# web scraping using BeautifulSoup: reading tables

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data from a table on transfermarkt.com. I was able to get the first 25 entry with the following code. However, I need to get the rest of the entries which are in the following pages. When I clicked on the second page, url does not change.

I tried to increase the range in the for loop but it gives an error. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop'
heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers = heads)
source = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
players = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
values = soup.find_all("td",{"class":"rechts hauptlink"})

playerslist = []
valueslist = []

for i in range(0,25):
    playerslist.append(players[i].text)
    valueslist.append(values[i].text)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":playerslist, "Values":valueslist})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter the url in the loop and also change your selectors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

players = []
values = []
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,21):
        r = s.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={page}', headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
        players += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .spielprofil_tooltip')]
        values += [i.text for i in soup.select('.items .rechts.hauptlink')]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":players, "Values":values})
```